# USB MBR Damaged

Tags: installation, boot, usb, live-usb

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on usb as live CD . I accidently removed the usb while the computer was running and after then i couldn't boot from USB. Tried other linux versions too nothing helped. IS there a way to fix the MBR of USB.

Answer (score 5):

You can try getting it fixed with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).  It worked for me.  Here is what I did to get it done.

First, you need to download TestDisk, and run it.  Connect the USB Drive and select Analyse disk.  Select `Rebuild MBR`, and `Write Boot`

Another thing you can try to fix the MBR:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install mbr
fdisk -l to find out which device is your flash drive
install-mbr /dev/sdx (replacing x with your flash device)
```

<sup>Source:Pen Drive Linux</sup>

Comment: TestDisk did not work in my case (could not write to a faulty USB disk). However, installing the mbr, as advised, worked and allowed recovery of the unusable disk.

Comment: Did not try TestDisk but `install-mbr` worked for me on a newish SanDisk 64 GB drive on Ubuntu 23.10. Thanks!