# Would not boot after swapped computer, stuck booting from live-boot USB

Tags: boot, live-usb, intel-nuc

My NUC5CPYH was running Mythbuntu and Myth-TV for several months when the fan died.  Intel agreed to replace the unit under warranty.  Now I deliberately set up my system to facilitate replacement of faulty parts with minimal disruption to TV services for the family.

The MBR, boot partition, operating system, user spaces, configuration and database were all on a 64GB USB flashdrive.  TV media storage, swap space, and tmpfs were all on partitions of a 1TB conventional hard drive:

`Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1961380         0   1961380   0% /dev
tmpfs             396336     41220    355116  11% /run
/dev/sdb2       59522180   8318284  48157240  15% /
tmpfs            1981672       140   1981532   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1981672         0   1981672   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1          45355      3458     41898   8% /boot/efi
/dev/sda2       38448788     49080  36446584   1% /tmp
/dev/sda3      907077056 843873704  17102056  99% /myth
tmpfs             396336         8    396328   1% /run/user/1000`

When the replacement box arrived - another NUC5CPYH - I plugged the drives and RAM into it, but it would not boot.  The BIOS setup recognised the UEFI partition was there and I could select it as the primary boot device, but when it tried to boot it would display `No boot device`.

I created a bootable live USB stick, booted from it (without problems), and was able to attach the other devices, and after a few attempts was able to get grub installed.  The system boots as it should now, straight into the Myth-TV front end as an appliance.

The only problem is now that it will only boot if I leave the bootable live-boot USB in!  Firstly, it's an ugly fat thing and it offends me having it hanging out of the front of my neat little NUC box.  Secondly, it serves no purpose as the system was operating fine without it before the box got replaced.  And thirdly it seems dumb to have an extra point of failure for no good reason.  And finally, occasionally I want that USB slot for other purposes!

So my question is really two questions I guess:

1. Is this because the MBR on the 64GB USB is corrupted?
2. How can I make the 64GB USB bootable again like it used to was?

All the instructions I could find about creating a live USB involved burning an ISO onto the device, which I absolutely do not want to do.

Comment: Didn't you have to leave the original 64G drive "hanging out of the front"?

Comment: Check your `/etc/fstab`. Your disks are probably mounted by UUID, which is different for your new disk. Run `blkid`, and adjust the `/etc/fstab` entries with the `PARTUUID=` values. Oh, and `man lsblk;man uuid;man fstab`

Comment: @waltinator, I don't want to mount the new device.  I want the original devices mounted, which is what I'm getting.  I checked `blkid` against `fstab` just to double-check and the UUIDs are all correct.  The problem is that the BIOS isn't recognising the 64GB device as a bootable USB so the system won't boot unless I keep the extra memory stick in there as well, which I don't want.

Comment: @OrganicMarble the 64GB drive is a Sandisk Ultrafit nano size drive so it sits nearly flush with the front panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it here: [USB MBR Damaged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314699/usb-mbr-damaged#314748)

I used `install-mbr /dev/sdc`

I shut down, removed the unwanted USB stick and rebooted from the original 64GB drive. Thank you for your helps.